# Shared module imported in AppModule

Tags: javascript, angular

I was reading the Angular documentation about modules, looking for a line that discourages importing a SharedModule inside the AppModule.

I didn't find anything about that, just a GitHub issue which states that it's better not to import it. However without any deep explain...

https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-ngrx-material-starter/issues/47

Angular discourages providing services in the Shared modules, which indeed I agree. But nothing else.

So my question is:

Since all my feature modules are lazy-loaded, and needs to import the shared module, but also my app component needs to use stuff provided by the same shared module, is it a bad practice to import it into the AppModule?

What may the consequences be?

Thanks in advance to anyone

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem with importing a `SharedModule` into the `AppModule` is that the providers will be injected twice in the feature modules (once by the `SharedModule`, once by the `AppModule`) which will result in the services not being singletons as they are supposed to be.

The common pattern to achieve that is not to expose providers directly on the `@NgModule` declaration but in a static `forRoot` function (the name is not mandatory, it's a convention) like that:

```
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
         ...
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

When importing the `SharedModule` into `AppModule`, use `SharedModule.forRoot()`, when you import it in a feature module just import it as `SharedModule`

Comment: Right! Thanks for the tip! Other than that you don't see any other "problems"? The only thing that worries me is that the SharedModule could grow in time, so will it be a huge monolith when deployed and requested by the user when loading AppModule?

Comment: For me, the only other thing that could happen is indeed the shared module to become very big, and cause every JS chunk (initial or lazy loaded) to become big too, with potentially unused code (even though the tree shaking looks quite efficient). But I think it's a problem that you'll have time to see coming, if it happens.

Answer (score 11):

Just have a look in this link [shared module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53183871/angular-7-pass-imported-module-to-feature-module) its not a bad practice to import your shared module in `AppModule`

Shared module is all about having common modules like if you have `form module` `some module` which is needed on all your modules instead of importing in all modules you can import it in `shared module` and export the same - check the link for further clarification

For service it can be injected just in one module the `AppModule` - Services are `injectable` and can be used in any module if it has been injected in root module

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Use this decorator in your service top it will automatically inject your service in root module

Thanks - Happy coding !!

Comment: Marking the answer below as accepted since it pointed out an important step, other than that, even yours is a valid one, so I up voted it. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: No issues - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As long as you avoid declaring services inside your shared module, I don't see any problem with it.