# Angular service providedIn VS forRoot

Tags: angular

I'd like to know if these two blocks of code are equivalent or not.

Can I use `providedIn` with the same result of `forRoot`?

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  constructor() { }
}
```

vs

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor() { }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: []
})
export class MyModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MyModule,
      providers: [
        MyService
      ]
    };
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MyModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[I would still keep my `MyModule` for single use  with the `providedId` singleton services]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`providedIn` will directly injects the `service` based on the value - if its 'root' it will directly inject in root `module` - this will help you to stop adding your `service` in module `[providers]`

Angular will inject the service in the `module` - If in case you are using Lazy loading modules - angular will create new injectors whenever you load other modules

If you use Lazy loading is better to go with `forRoot()` injection on the modules and make sure your `service` doesn't create multiple injectors

Hope this helps you - Happy coding !!

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53186466/shared-module-imported-in-appmodule) for more info

Comment: So just in case of lazy loading are you sure using provideIn don't give you a singleton if you can build a simple running example I'd be most grateful :) thanks for the help

Comment: You can check that link for further clarification - thanks :)

Comment: providedIn worked just fine for using singleton service instance within lazy-loaded components. I really don't understand why angular introduced providedIn while forRoot was already in place!

Check out this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-treeshakable-providedin-3pbafd

Answer (score 18):

Using `providedIn` vs `providers[]`:

1. `providedIn` is the new Angular way of doing DI. `providedIn` was brought since Angular 6
2. The official name is "Tree-shakeable providers" - instead of module providing all its services, it is now the service itself declaring where it should be provided
3. Using `providedIn: 'root'` removes the need to import the library module at all, we can simply inject needed services and it just works

Comment: Yes, in this way `providedIn` is better than `forRoot` Because it is more tree shakeable.

Comment: Then why do we still use `RouterModule` with `forRoot` pattern?

Comment: @saivishnutammineni, I suppose because with `providedIn` you cannot configure provider with a custom config, and we need to provide our custom routes for the `Router` service.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `forRoot` and `provideIn` both are equivalent since both will create the only and only one singleton for the app. Even though it being loaded in lazy loaded component.

Refer this nice article on it - https://medium.com/@chrishouse/when-to-use-angulars-forroot-method-400094a0ebb7