# Angular providedIn root and forRoot pattern

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi what is the difference between Angular's `providedIn: root` at service level and using the `forRoot()` module pattern?
I have already seen this answer [Angular service providedIn VS forRoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53251849/angular-service-providedin-vs-forroot) which says there is no difference.

1. Does this stand true even if we are creating a library which gives a service?
2. Why do we need to use `forRoot` pattern with router module then? Why isn't router service provided in root? Any compatibility related reason?

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to provide a service in a module, do it inside the service,

`@Injectable({ providedIn: 'any', })`

With providedIn: 'any', all eagerly loaded modules share a singleton instance; however, lazy loaded modules each get their own unique instance

OR

u can choose the following way:

```
providedIn: YourModule
```

into your service

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. But this doesn't answer the question.